# Doctrine y CodeIgniter 3 No reconoce la clase

Tags: codeigniter, mvc, doctrine

Buen dia a todos.

Estoy creando un proyecto con Doctrine, el problema es cuando intento hacer algo como esto :

```
$message = $this->em->find('Entities\PdContact', 1);
```

desde el modelo, obtengo el siguiente error:

> Class 'Entities\PdContact' does not exist

espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, Gracias.

Comment: Puede ser que necesite el path entero de la entidad tal que: "\APIBundle\Entities\PdContact"

Comment: Suscribo lo dicho por @victorlopezsanchez, tiene pinta de que el namespace de la clase `PdContact` no está completo. Podrías enseñárnosla?